# select a value where it doesnt exist in another table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables 
How can i get more information such as name and gender?

```
@A
ID  Name Gender .....
1   A
2   B
3   C
5   D
6   E

@B
ID PosID
3   1 
5   2
```

I use this sql to query.

```
SELECT ID
FROM A
EXCEPT
SELECT ID 
FROM B;
```

I got this from the result.

```
ID
1
2
6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `not exists`, for instance:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   a 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   b 
                   WHERE  a.id = b.id);
```

Or use a `left outer join`.  Or `not in`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT  L.*
FROM    Table1 L
LEFT JOIN
        Table2 R
ON      R.ID = L.ID
WHERE   R.ID IS NULL
```

**NOT IN**

```
SELECT  L.*
FROM    Table1 L
WHERE   L.ID NOT IN
    (
    SELECT  ID
    FROM    Table2 R
    )
```

**NOT EXIST**

```
SELECT  L.*
FROM    Table1 L
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT  NULL
    FROM    Table2 R
    WHERE   R.ID = L.ID
    )
```